How to Perform Network Diffusion on a Weighted Graph with Multiple Edge Attributes?
I am working on a network diffusion problem where my graph has multiple edge attributes, and I need advice on how to effectively combine these attributes for the diffusion process.
I have a weighted graph where each edge has several attributes, such as contribution, overlapping genes, and correlation. Each of these attributes has a different range of values. The challenge with multiple edge attributes is that they complicate the process of determining a single, meaningful edge weight that accurately reflects the combined influence of all attributes. This is crucial for the diffusion process, which relies on edge weights to model the flow of information or influence through the network.
Combining these attributes into a single edge weight is not straightforward because:

Different Scales: Attributes can have different ranges (e.g., contribution between 0-1, overlapping genes between 0-100, correlation between -1 and 1).
Relative Importance: Determining the relative importance of each attribute in the context of diffusion is subjective and challenging.
Potential Conflicts: Some attributes might conflict with each other in terms of their influence on diffusion.

What are the best practices for determining the weights of multiple edge attributes in a network diffusion process?
Thank you very much.
